# How to SetWindowPos Z-order of a window to just under the activated window?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a side-bar app (dialog Win forms app) that controls an associated IE browser using Watin automation.

When the side-bar is activated I want to also bring the associated browser forward, *but I do not want the win forms app to lose focus*.

I have tried many settings/variations of the following code, but the winforms app loses focus to the browser as soon as it is activated, so no buttons on the form can be pressed!

```
    private void BrowserControlForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Browser != null)
        {
            SetWindowPos(this.Browser.hWnd, -1, this.Width, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, 0);
        }
    }
```

**Q. What is the correct way to place the other window just under (Z-order-wise) the current activated (Winforms) window?**

*The example code also resizes the browser take up the remainder of the screen, but that is not relevant to the problem.* More of the existing code would not assist in solving the problem.

**Updates:**

SWP_NOACTIVATE fails to bring the browser window forward at all:

```
SetWindowPos(this.CareCheckBrowser.hWnd, -1, this.Width, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, 0x0010 /*SWP_NOACTIVATE*/);
```

Insert after the current window's handle still loses focus:

```
SetWindowPos(this.Browser.hWnd, (int)this.Handle, this.Width, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, 0);
```

Setting the current window to the top after the browser does not work as the focus is already lost (so button clicks are still ignored). The focus/activation just flicks back and forth on any clicks e.g.:

```
SetWindowPos(this.Browser.hWnd, 0, this.Width, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, 0x0004);
SetForegroundWindow(this.Browser.hWnd);
SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant: That is a `Form` method. I need to bring forward the separate IE browser instance. Can that be applied to a separate IE instance (for which I only have a `hWnd`)?

Comment: Then you'll need the SWP_NOACTIVATE option for SetWindowPos().

Comment: @Hans Passant: My comments on the update were wrong (cut & paste error). I already tried SWP_NOACTIVATE. Can you spot any problems with that example?

Comment: Why dont you call *SetForegroundWindow()* two times. One for browser and one for your window.

Comment: @valter: If the dialog does not have focus, but is visible, pressing one of its actions buttons causes activation and the action button becomes unclickable (basically focus flicks back and forth). Will update the trial of this suggestion.

Comment: Is the browser window minimized?

Comment: @valter: No. The users just alt-tab to other app, then return to the side-bar app. The browser is just behind the other apps.

Comment: "Vote to close" based on lack of complete example? *Really?* This is not a "this code is not working" question as the existing code would never do the job required so a more detailed example *would not help*. This type of question should be answerable without further details (and it has been) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all open window handles and peek those that are not minimized. Iterate through the list except the handle of browser:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd); //returns true if window is minimized

private List<IntPtr> windowsHandles = new List<IntPtr>();
//fill list with window handles

for (i = 0; i < windowsHandles.Count; i++)
{
    if (windowsHandles[i] != browserHandle && windowsHandles[i] != this.Handle && !IsIconic(windowsHandles[i]))
    { 
        SetWindowPos(windowsHandles[i], HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
}
```

Valter

Comment: I extended this to exclude both the current app hWnd as well as the browser hWnd and it works a treat. *"Don't raise the bridge, lower the river"*. Well done. Thanks :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Just for curiosity. How to you get the handles, with *GetWindow() or EnumWindows()*?

Comment: I am using `EnumWindows` with `IsWindowVisible()` and `!IsIconic()` to filter out just the open app window handles.